# How long it takes to fill an inflatable to a certain pressure?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, compressed-air

I am trying to figure out the inflation/how to calculate the time it takes to fill something to a certain pressure.

I have an [inflatable dock](https://www.boteboard.com/products/inflatable-dock-7-classic) I am filling with a [portable pump](https://outdoormaster.com/products/electric-paddle-board-pump-shark-ii).

The dock is 7ft x 7ft x 8in -> which is about 32.75 cubic feet (or 245 gallons or 925 liters) and is supposed to fill it to at least 6 PSIG (20.7 PSIA)

The pump has 2 stage - 350 L/min (12.3 CFM) to 1PSIG, and then 70L/min (2.47 CFM) up to 20PSI.

So I am trying to map out how long it would take to fill this. The problem is I see varying formulas. A) [Here](https://www.vmacair.com/blog/work-time-fill-type-questions-using-simple-logic) and B)[here](https://www.about-air-compressors.com/fill-an-air-tank/), but also the problem is this is for tanks and not inflatables, so is there a difference. My assumption is that if I use, the method in Source A example 1, the assumption is it starts at atmosphere right? Is it that it should take 925L/350L/min to get to 0 PSI, and then do the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take it to mean -

- 1 PSIG is really just expanding the flat dock to its inflated size so you're going to need 925 (L) / 350 (L/min) = 3 minutes to get that far.
- 20 PSI = 1.37 bar (above atmospheric) so that means you're going to need to pump in another 925 × 1.37 = 1267 L of free air. This will occur at 70 L/min so will take 1267 / 70 = 18 minutes.
- Total time = 3 + 18 = 21 minutes.

This all assumes that the pump works to specification but I suspect that it might vary during the high-pressure pumping and you might find that the specifications may have been written by an optimist.

---

From the comments:

> What if I were to add 100 ft of 1inch ID tubing? By my calculations this should only add ~15 L extra to fill, but is there a way to account for pressure drop?

Pressure drop will only occur while there is air flow. As the pressure in the inflatable reaches that of the compressor the flow will reduce and so will the pressure drop. You can check the drop by inflating at the compressor with the 100 ft of hose in line and a pressure gauge at the compressor and at the inflatable. (Do a calibration check first by by comparing both gauges with the hose outlet blocked.)

Comment: This makes sense. Follow up: what if I were to add 100ft of 1inch ID tubing? By my calculations this should only add ~15L extra to fill, but is there a way to account for pressure drop? https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pressure-drop-compressed-air-pipes-d_852.html

Is it simply add the additional pressure drop (so e.g. if 2 PSI drop, then calculate as if filling to 22PSI rather than 20PSI)?

Comment: See the update.